# How can a view that is not based on a table with an index be added to a Database First EF 6.x project

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a View which is not based on a table with a primary index (it's actually based on other views). I can't seem to add it to an Entity Framework Database First (6.x) project. I get the error/warning that a key could not be inferred.

What is necessary to get this View into my model? I can create an entity manually but then can't map it to the View. I tried adding a column called Index to the View (just a column with a newid()) but that didn't work either.

Comment: Sounds like you are missing a primary key. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Here's the code that the view is made of. I tried to fake a primary key with the newid() as the first column: SELECT
        newid() AS Indx
       , Base.PatientName
      
FROM......